# Springboot 3.2.1 with GET URI pathvariable cannot bind to the value to variable, hence Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available error

Tags: spring-boot-3

After upgrading to Springboot3.2.1 cannot bind the PathVariable in the GET URI mapping to the @PathVariable studentId
EX: GET /info/{studentId}  is the URI path
and the correspoding java code:
@ApiParam(value="Student identifier", required=true)@NotBlank @Size(min=3 , max=5)@PathVariable String studentId,

using Spring3.1.x the above GET endpoint will get mapped with the path variable sent in URI ex: /info/123, here studentId will get assigned with 123.

Where as upgrading to Spring3.2.1 the above code will result into
"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either.] with root cause....

Solution:

Explictly provided the pathVariable with name.
Example in the above studentId is the path variable value being assigned hence with the below update made it to work
@ApiParam(value="Student identifier", required=true)@NotBlank @Size(min=3 , max=5)@PathVariable("studentId" String studentId

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77828815/8226835