# .[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/ocm] threw exception

Tags: server

.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/ocm] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.

I am using
Springboot 3.2.1
Java 17
Spring 6

I have update Requestpamarm

Answer (score 1):

The version of Spring Framework used by Spring Boot 3.2 no longer attempts to deduce parameter names by parsing bytecode. If you experience issues with dependency injection or property binding, you should double check that you are compiling with the -parameters option. See this section of the "Upgrading to Spring Framework 6.x" wiki for more details.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes